# How to avoid escape characters in gulp task logs?

Tags: escaping, gulp

This is the Gulp logs that are created:

> [Info],Code repository head matched with CodeTagId:,21.00.01.08,for GradeITCode repository
>
> [Info],Content repository head matched with ContentTagId:,21.00.01.08,for PCTContent repository.
>
> git rev-parse HEAD (log : false),
>
> [Info],Code repository head matched with CodeTagId:,21.00.01.08,for PCTCode >repository.
>
> Finished,'[36mValidateConfigParams[39m',after,[35m2.15s[39mStarting,'[36mcleanPackageLocation[39m'...
>
> [Info],Cleaning Package Location Started
>
> [Info],Cleaning Package Location complete
>
> Finished,'[36mcleanPackageLocation[39m',after,[35m1.4 min[39m
>
> Starting,'[36mbuildGradeIT[39m'...

The [36m and [39m are special characters which need to be removed and are only present in the Finished and Starting logs.

The native stdout.write and console.log have been overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It eventually turned out to be the characters inserted by Chalk.js which provides Colors to the Logs on Console.

When the Stdout function was overwritten, the characters got printed in the Log FIle.

chalk.stripColor(string) turned out to be my solution.